# jQuery Autocomplete and correction of Keyword - google style

Tags: pattern-matching, jquery-autocomplete, google-suggest

I have an autocomplete box with jQuery Autocomplete Plugin. I have also an autocorrection of my words, what mean, I know if someone types wrong keyword and I am returning the correct one.

This what I want now is to display the correction in the way like Google makes it:

[image]

I know that this features is building somehow with 2 input boxes. Has someone an example or tutorial for this?

Thanks
Nik